# Using TTPhotoViewController without the Three20's URL system?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, view, three20

Whenever I add the TTPhotoViewController to my window , it appears without a top navigation bar and once I tap the image, the bottom navigation overlay and the status bar (the springboard one) will disappear permanently. **How do I create a top navigation bar so I can add a button to hide the view after it was shown and how do I restore the overlays/toolbars after a tap?**

```
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
```

I am not using Three20's URL mapping system because I see no point in doing that. I think that might be causing the problem but I think there is a *sensible* solution. Using the URL system is **not** a solution for me.

Comment: Just because you can't figure it out or want to take the time to learn the framework doesnt make it crap. Production level apps with millions of downloads use the excellent three20 navigation system with no issues and benefit greatly from the built in persistence, convenience and stability of TTNavigator.  If you don't want to use it, thats fine, but don't use StackOverflow to express your opinions.  This isn't a blog, but a question and answer site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changing some of the view controllers code. For some reason the show/hide function was always being called with the '**hide**' argument. No idea why though,

Answer (score 1):

Why not just like this:
- Create a ViewController inheriting from TTPhotViewController

```
MGSPhotoViewController *photoViewController = [[MGSPhotoViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:photoViewController animated:YES];
[photoViewController release];
```

it works like a charm.

One thing you need to consider:

If you com back to the previous view controller you'll need to change the tintColor of the NavigationBar because it remains black somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I know you've already solved this, but in case others run in to this thread: a way to avoid this issue without any custom code is to make sure TTPhotoViewController is the rootViewController of a UINavigationController

Comment: Yes, sorry for the delay. Make a UINavigation controller as follows

[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myTTPhotoViewController]